# Am I using the word "Hajimari" correctly in judo?

Tags: nuances, word-usage, terminology, sports

I am an instructor in a Finnish judo club. At the end of each session, ***owari!*** is announced and the students line up. I understand that owari means *over* or *end*, but there are lots of Finnish judo clubs that use the word at the start of the session as well (as if it meant *to stand in line*).

Now, I have started to use ***hajimari!*** for this *beginning* line up. I have very little knowledge of Japanese, but I am aware there are also forms ***hajimaru*** and ***hajimeru***. (I use ***hajime*** to start exercises, randori etc.)

So, the students know that when I say this, they gather in a line - but is this correct from a Japanese viewpoint?

Doing research on this is surprisingly difficult. I would like to know what are the differences between those forms, and which one of them would be the best counterpart for the ***owari***.

Please, if you could be so kind and avoid using any kana or kanji in your answer.

### Edit:

First of all, I' like to thank all of you for the answers. I am going to be a bit vain and accept the answer that best suits **me**, that answer even grants me the **choice**.

I should have emphasized that much like **owari**, my intention on announcing **hajimari** is to tell students that it is time to put away phones, exercise balls etc. and gather in a line, tie their belts and wait in silence. Most of the answers said that **hajimari** is grammatically acceptable, so I'll take it - I don't care if it is not customary. I would like to think it means a greater beginning than just **hajime** which to me sounds more instantaneous *start!*

As I said, in some Finnish judo clubs some of the japanese words and terms are used just because *they have always been used in this context*, even without proper knowledge of the meaning of the words. This is why **owari** is sometimes used incorrectly as a command to stand in line. Some even say *let's go stand in owari*. Japanese is not so much spoken in class, rather some key terms are said in order to teach students the minimal vocabulary.

- Hajimari (this is my addition to my class)
- Mokuso (close your eyes, clear your mind)
- Mokuso yame
- Rei
- Hajime (start randori, start yakusoku keiko)
- Mate (wait: get up and start again)
- Kootai (Koutai? switch partners)
- Yame (stop randori etc.)
- Owari (the end)

Obviously there are a lot more, but I included here the terms that control the flow of the exercises.

Comment: Kudos to you as a martial arts instructor for researching the background of the traditional words used in the dojo

Comment: `the best counterpart for owari.` -- The counterpart of *Owari!* as an instruction would be *Hajime!*, but it is an announcement "Start (something) now!" (So you can use *hajime* to start exercises, randori etc.) `I have started to use hajimari! for this beginning line up.` -- Shouting "Hajimari!" sounds weird, either for announcing "Start now!" or "Line up!", I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have ask yourself what message you really want to deliver, in terms of the "beginning".

## Command

As in "*You shall begin to line up*"

Do you want to "command" your students? Then it's **Hajime**. After all, you are in charge to initiate, so this makes sense.

## Statement

As in "*The beginning approaches, it's time to line up*"

Do you want to "explain" that the beginning is approaching? Then it's **Hajimari**. This is totally acceptable - story-tellers have been saying "Hajimari Hajimari" (even twice to sound dramatic) to indicate the beginning of the tale. In this case, you are not necessarily the one who is initiating the linining-up - perhaps another entity including mother nature, god(s), universe, etc. However in the martial arts industry (unfortunately, it is practically an industry now days) this approach is never used.

## Choice

So you see, neither is wrong. The "do" in "Judo" resembles a "path" that one follows. In Japan's conservative culture, students are always "commanded", which is the path you may follow. But nothing is stopping you to change the approach towards a humble and friendly style. Call it innovative, unique, weird or unnatural, it's up to you.

Answer (score 7):

I am not particularly knowledgeable about judo, but the usual phrases used in Japanese sports or military contexts are:

- 整列！ *Sēretsu!* ("Line up!") [pronunciation](https://forvo.com/word/%E9%9B%86%E5%90%88/)
- 集合！ *Shūgō!* ("Gather!") [pronunciation](https://ja.forvo.com/word/%E6%95%B4%E5%88%97/)

Of course these can be used also near the end of a class, so they are not technically counterparts of *owari*. But I think nothing directly derived from *hajimaru/hajimeru* would work as you expect.

*Hajimari* ("Beginning!") may be at least better than *owari*, but it still doesn't make much sense as a command to line up. Besides, it's too close to *hajime* used at the beginning of a match.

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what I am aiming for. I want to tell everyone at the dojo (that extends to a boxing gym unfortunately) that the judo class session is now starting. Students put away all the equipment they might have had, clear the tatami of balls and such, get in line, straighten their gi and shut up. Their parents (they sometimes stay and watch the session) keep quiet and understand that sensei has taken over and is not to be interrupted.

Comment: ^ @diynevala `I want to tell everyone at the dojo that the judo class session is now starting. Students put away... and shut up. Their parents keep quiet and understand that sensei has taken over and is not to be interrupted.` ← In that case I suggest shouting 「始めます！Hajimemasu!」, not 「始まり！Hajimari!」 Shouting "Hajimari, hajimari~!" to announce the start of a class/lesson would sound like a joke.

Comment: @Chocolate Hajimemasu = **Let's begin? That sounds good as well**. I am sorry that I am a bit stuck with the idea that **hajimari** would ultimately be the best choice. It seems that while grammatically correct, it has kind of a cultural stigma among japanese, it is too connected to stage plays? Much like rainbows are so often used in LGBT culture that it is hard to use it in any other instances. NOTE! I am not starting discussion about lgbt politics, nor should anyone here.

Comment: @diynevala A 100% grammatical phrase is often 100% nonsense. Three native speakers here, including myself, are saying hajimari is funny at least. If you just need to say "I begin", hajimeru (blunt/dignified) or hajimemasu (polite) would make much more sense.

Answer (score 7):

With all due respect, this seems to be one of those cases where learners can tell what is grammatical but only native (or near-native) speakers can tell what is really idiomatic.

Grammatically speaking, there should be nothing wrong with *hajimari* as it is to the intransitive verb *hajimaru* what *owari* is to *owaru*, which is also (mostly) intransitive. However, it sounds very odd as something you shout at the beginning of anything. *Owari* in that context is understood as meaning something along the lines of “That’s all, ”“This is it,” and so on. No such meaning is attached to *hajimari*. It is just a neutral word for “beginning.”

*Hajime* is derived from the transitive verb *hajimeru*, and in that context it is understood as an instruction to start doing something. Its opposite is *yame* from *yameru*, which means to stop doing whatever you are doing now.

I would suggest you take in naruto’s advice.

Answer (score 4):

Language aspects are answered in existing answers. Just let me share some google searches. I have no experience of Judo either, so take my comments with a grain of salt.

---

[This](https://okwave.jp/qa/q3383111.html) asks more or less the same question in Japanese. The answer says, there is no particular shouting. According to it, a session starts like

- The instructor calls students for starting, just like in a normal conversation. E.g, (in English) "Boys, now we are starting..."
- Everybody sits down (or up) in [seiza](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HN8nByO3y3c?t=21).
- A head student makes three calls:
- Shōmen ni rei = *Bow to the front*, then everybody makes a bow.
- Sensei ni rei = *Bow to the teacher*, then everybody makes a bow.
- Otagai ni rei = *Bow to each other*, then everybody makes a bow.

This takes place also in the ending. ([This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCGi36l51gM) does mostly the same). The first shomen seems to refer originally to the [altar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamidana) of Shintoism (Japanese native religion).

I guess doing all these would be too much, so as naruto suggested, using *Seiretsu!* for lining up and then *Rei!* for bowing would be good enough (in terms of Japanese-ishness).

---

BTW I wish I could see Finnish students starting at the shout of *owari!*, which would look a bit surreal. Don't be offended, but that just makes me think how difficult it was for people using different languages to understand each other in pre-modern days...

Comment: It is not surreal: if nobody tells what owari means, but other students always seem to gather in a line, it is easy to think it means **stand in line**.

Answer (score 3):

These words are all either verbs, or verb-derived nouns.

- *Hajimaru*: intransitive verb, "to begin, to start", as in "something starts or begins on its own".

  - *Hajimari*: noun derivation from the verb, "beginning, start", as in the natural or spontaneous beginning of something -- in line with the intransitive nature of the underlying verb.
- *Hajimeru*: transitive verb, "to begin", as in "to begin or start something".

  - *Hajime*: noun derivation from the verb, "beginning, start", as in the intentional or deliberate beginning of something -- in line with the transitive nature of the underlying verb.
- *Owaru*: intransitive verb, "to finish, to end", as in "something ends or finishes on its own".

  - *Owari*: noun derivation from the verb, "ending, finish", as in the natural or spontaneous ending of something -- in line with the intransitive nature of the underlying verb.

I'm not that familiar with judo as a discipline or how classes are run.  That said, shouting *"Owari!"* at the b̲e̲g̲i̲n̲n̲i̲n̲g̲ of a class sounds like a linguistic mistake to me.

Comment: I agree on the linguistic mistake - finnish people know little about japanese language, but some traditions are there just because... well someone did things this way and nobody bothered to research. Most use owari at the end, some think you can use it anytime like "everybody stand in line".

Comment: I think owari as "game over" or "the end" of the movie, in this case it is like an announcement "session is over" or "class dismissed". Is this correct and comprehensible?

Comment: @diynevala, yes, _"owari"_ just means "the end", as in "it's done / finished / ended". At least some Japanese movies that I've seen have 「終【おわ】り」 (_Owari_) at the close.

Comment: By the same logic, can I use the "hajimari" as an announcement "session is beginning / has begun / begins right now"?

Comment: @diynevala, sure, that works.  :)

Comment: @diynevala `can I use the "hajimari" as an announcement "session is beginning / has begun / begins right now"?` -- No, shouting "hajimari!" to announce "session is beginning / has begun / begins now" sounds weird to my native ear, I'm afraid. We use "hajime!" in such contexts. (We use "hajimari" in a phrase "Hajimari, hajimari!", which is an announcement of starting a traditional stage play or 紙芝居.)

Comment: @Chocolate, muchos arigatos for the clarification. 

Comment: Unrelated to the content, but did you try to underline the word "beginning"? Because [it looks kind of broken on Chrome 100, macOS 12.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5aQr.png).

Comment: @AndrewT. , interesting, must be a font rendering issue. It’s using the Unicode character for combining underline, since SE has arbitrarily disallowed proper HTML or CSS underlining.

Comment: @Chocolate Traditional stage play? Is it said because audience should be quiet and focus on the play? That would be perfect..

Comment: No we don't say it to make the audience be quiet and focus. I think we say the phrase 「Hajimari, hajimari!」 to announce the start of a casual play (not a formal one like Kabuki or Noh) often for kids, or some fun thing, some people use it for a start of a festival or even a party. It sounds casual, can sound a bit childish, like, "Fun thing is beginning! Let's have fun! Exciting! Yay [Applaud]".

Answer (score 2):

Wherever work sends me, I usually find a martial arts class to train with, for a few months.

After studying karate in my youth, as well as in my itinerate middle age, I should like to add 'seiretsu', as provided by @Naruto, is by far the most widely used command in Japanese martial arts, other than the native language, for the class to fall in, across the Western hemisphere.

With 'hajime' and 'yame' being used, respectively, at either end of a bout of sparring or wrestling.